# How To Summarize A Rollup Relationship That Cross References A Custom Object?

Tags: salesforce, relational-database, salesforce-lightning

We are trying to implement a University system for students, faculty, and staff to be able to better manage course registrations as well as other enrollment activities.

**Consider the following problem:** When a student registers for a course, the course needs to get added to the students bill as a billing line item. The bill needs to have a total price of all the courses that have been registered for that particular student. Note: We've tried to keep the process manual in order to simplify the requirements.

We have identified 4 custom objects and some important fields:

1. **Courses** - *Course Name*:(Primary Key), *Course Size*:(Number), *Course Price*:(Currency), *Start Date*:(Date), *End Date*:(Date), *Students Enrolled*:(Rollup Count)
2. **Course Registrations** - *Course Registration Number*:(Primary Key), *Course List*:(Master-Detail), *Student*:(Lookup), *Course Price*:(Formula), *Course Credits*:(Formula)
3. **Billing Line Item** - *Billing Line Item Number*:(Primary Key), *Course Registration*:(Master-Detail), *Bill*:(Master-Detail), *Course Price*:(Formula)
4. **Bill** - *Bill Name*:(Primary Key), *Student*:(Lookup)

We know in order to summarize the total of all course prices, we need to make the Billing Line Item the detail object and the Bill the master object. We want to perform a Rollup Summary on all the Billing Line Item prices.

We've also made the Billing Line Item the detail object and the Course Registration a master object. This is because without a Course Registration, there is no need for a Billing Line Item to exist. Also the Course Registration has the *Course Price* via a formula which needs to be used in order to summarize the total cost of all courses.

I've seen online that you are unable to summarize a cross-reference object. We are getting confused as to how we should summarize all the prices associated with each course. Any help would be greatly appreciated. We can provide screenshots if requested!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the reference to course price should be a formula. Next year you'll change prices and it'll retroactively screw your past invoices up? (and you wouldn't even have field history tracking on the formula field, only on the Course. So if you don't know where to look it'll be as if it always was this price)

Make it a normal editable Number field (although Currency type would be better) and use workflow / "early" flow / process builder or code to populate the list price on save. You don't lose anything (as you create new line item now you also don't see the price until you save, formula field doesn't show up on "new", right?). This normal field will already be rollup-able but you can spice things up by adding discount % or differentiate between list price, sales price... Look how much stuff is on built-in [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm)

If you feel really fancy - you can include something that on change of Course's list price would cascade down to all registrations and billing items where status = Open(?) and update the list price...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have thought about using the process builder to auto-populate the list price when a new record is created. The object in this process builder is obviously the Course Registration object (i.e. when a new Course Registration object is created --> create Billing Line Item object). The only difficulty I'm having with the process builder is how to assign my Bill & Course Registration fields. Because these fields are Master objects, they require an input. I have setup these objects to be auto-number fields and I'm not sure how I can assign these fields in the process.

Comment: Edit: I have figured out how to assign the Course Registration field (because this is the object that starts the process I can simply assign the Course Registration ID field). I am still unsure how to create the Bill field? I'm guessing I need to relate the Bill and the Course Registration? Either that or the Course Registration and the Billing Line Item. Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: Does Bill have a status? I'd detach it, on registration you enter CourseRegistration and that's it. Then have a separate button for monthly(?) billing run that finds registrations without children (bill items), checks if student has Bill header with status "Open" (and creates the header if none found) and links it all up. In a pinch you could pull it off with a Flow but sounds too tricky for process builder. I'd code it ;) Consider asking on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ if you're after low code solution, they might have some clever ideas.

Comment: Hello, I was finally able to find a way around this problem. I related the Course Registration object to the Bill. I made Course Registration a required Lookup relationship. Basically if a student want to registers for a course, they have to select their associated Bill. Once this relationship is defined and a Bill is associated with the Course Registration, I have a process that automatically creates a Billing Line Item and inputs the necessary fields. Finally, as you suggested I made the Course Price a currency datatype, automated the process and performed the rollup summary. THANK YOU!!! :)

Comment: I'm not convinced but you do you ;) I'd still put a status and maybe lookup filter to avoid attempts of new registration piggybacking on an already paid bill ;)